# log4net disable question

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I am currently coding a very large project, I am near the end of the development stage and have sent out an evaluation version to the consumer so he can check for bugs and what not.
He told me that there was a large log file being created every time the application starts up.
After some investigation I found out that the log file was created using log4net via an external DLL which I use in my application. 
I have searched a bit and found you can disable log4net logs through an app.config file and adding several values there, I tried this but with no success, the logs are being created no matter which value I use in the xml config file.

I have no access to the external DLL source code and I have searched for an xml configuration file that the DLL uses - but have not found anything.

I would like to disable log4net completely, the Logs are pretty useless for me since I use my own log engine, which i can configure any way I want it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: log4net can also use application config file( web.config or .exe.config). So check within them if section for log4net exists or not. I am quire curious as to how logging is happening w/o specifying what file to write to.

Answer (score 0):

When you call for log4net you can specify the config file. 
check the log4net initialization in your app to see where it gets the instructions.

another way is to configure log4net to use windows event log rather than a file and configure a limit on the log size.

Comment: The problem is that the call for log4net isn't in my code, its inside the external DLL, and I dont have access to its source code

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the config file that log4Net uses; by default it is named `log4net.config`

If that's not the case, I would suggest firing up [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to check which file it is using.

[BTW, I would be slightly curious about using a third-party DLL that I didn't have control over.]

Comment: Will check with Process Monitor. I trust the author of the DLL completely so I'm not that worried about the lack of control. How can I specify the config file that log4net uses without access to the code that creates the instance ?

Comment: I checked with the process monitor but could not find any call to the log4net.config file or something of that nature, only the call to open the log4net.dll

Answer (score 0):

Log4net can also be configured programmatically. I wonder if the dll is doing that?  If the dll is configuring log4net programmatically maybe you could use the log4net api to turn it off. I don't have a good example of how to do that now because I am on my phone.